# Css for textbox

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I do to add a css rule for all textbox ?
I know that :

```
input{}
```

is for all the input but if I want especially the type="text" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```css
input[type="text"]
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
input[type="text"] { color: orange; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```css
input[type="text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your platform supports attribute selectors, then great--use those. But if it doesn't, you'll need to apply a class attribute to each of your text inputs to distinguish them from radio buttons or check boxes in CSS.